# Sortbuilders aren't working- sorting by date (spring data & elasticsearch)

Tags: sorting, logging, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I store documents in elasticsearch that way :

```
{
  "_index" : "logstash-2017.10.19",
  "_type" : "logs",
  "_id" : "AV8z6knXrN3q6F4uePZp",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "service" : "service1",
    "date" : "2017-10-19T10:12:56.939Z",
    "level" : "INFO",
    "field" : "RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1",
    "classe" : "org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin",
    "msg" : "<Application shutdown requested.>",
    "@version" : "1",
    "@timestamp" : "2017-10-19T09:15:10.811Z"
  }
```

I want to get the research results sorted by date (here is my code ):

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date").gte(from).lte(to))
            .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("level", level)).must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("msg", message))
            .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("service", serviceName));
    SearchQuery sq = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(index).withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 1))
            .withQuery(qb).withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("date").order(SortOrder.DESC)).build();
    List<Logs> listLogs = loadListLogs(sq);
```

But the result i get isn't sorted at all! HELP